# Use response from one $http in another $http in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, http, promise, angular-promise

First of all I want to use $http in order to receive some data (e.g. students), then I want to make another $http call to get e.g. studentDetails. After that I want to append some part of studentDetails to students JSON. 
Also I need response from the first call in order to create the url for the second call.

Problem is that I cannot access response of the first http call inside the another. 
Does anybody know how this can be done?

```
var getStudents = function(){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.get("https://some_url")
   .success(function(response){
      deferred.resolve(response);
   }).error(function(errMsg){
      deferred.reject(errMsg);
   });
   return deferred.promise;
}
var appendStudentDetails = function(){
  getStudents().then(function(response){
     var studentsWithDetails = response;
     for(var i=0; i<studentsWithDetails.length; i++){
        $http.get("some_url/"+studentWithDetails[i].user.details+"/")
           .success(function(res){

             //here I want to append the details, 
             //received from the second http call, to each student 
             //of the array received from the first http call 

             //PROBLEM: I cannot access response of the
             //first http call inside the another
           })
     }
  })
```

Comment: You can simply store the earlier http call response in your scope variable and use it in your next call's success callback.

Comment: it should be: `var studentsWithDetails = response.data;`

Comment: What is present inside response?

Comment: @Vivz Inside response I have array of 20 students with some information, but from the second http call I am getting some other information that I would like to append to each of the array's element

Comment: Are you sure that studentsWithDetails  is an array. Can you console and check

Comment: @Vivz It is. Array of 20 objects. Response or studentsWithDetails (from the first call), and res (from the second call) are fine, I just cannot access studentsWithDetails inside .success part of the second call.

Comment: @VitezKoja *"I just cannot access studentsWithDetails inside"* That shouldn't cause any problems. Your problem is most likely something else. Do you get any error messages? Does it actually finish all expected requests? Can you share some of the code inside your inner `success`-callback - are you using the `i`-variable somewhere besides the url?

Comment: @VitezKoja If you are getting the response correctly, then it should work. Maybe try checking the below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the deferred anti-pattern as well as the deprecated success/error-callbacks. You should instead use `then`, since it returns a promise, and you can chain promises.

Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
function getStudents(){
    return $http.get('[someurl]');
}
function appendStudentDetails(studentsWithDetails){
    for(var i=0; i<studentsWithDetails.length; i++){
        appendSingleStudentDetails(studentsWithDetails[i]);
    }
}
function appendSingleStudentDetails(singleStudent){
    $http.get("some_url/"+singleStudent.user.details+"/")
        .then(function(res){
            // Append some stuff
            singleStudent.stuff = res.data;
        });
}

// Call it like this:
getStudents()
    .then(function(response){ return response.data; })
    .then(appendStudentDetails);
```

I decided to structure the `appendStudentDetails` function a little differently, based on its name, but you could as easily just call `getStudents()` within the method as you did before.

*Beware not to use the `i`-variable inside your inner `then`-function, as that would cause you troubles with closure.*

**Edit: Fixed example to avoid problem with `i` being under closure.**

Comment: Thank you!! I still have a problem in accessing studentsWithDetails[i] inside .then. It is undefined. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I've fixed the above example to avoid using `i` within the inner `then`-callback. The reason is that the variable `i` was referenced under closure, so when the callback was called, the loop would have finished and `i` would have been the wrong value for every call to the callback. This might fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now! It is a very nice solution! :)

Comment: Awesome mate. Glad it helped.